# Cypress : npx cypress open command not working

Tags: automation, cypress

I have downloaded nodejs and installed and set up in the path environment variable.
Downloaded Vscode and then created a project folder(automation).

From the terminal in the folder , provided the command npx init cypress
and then install cypress

wrote a piece of code and then tried executing npx cypress open, but nothing coming up.
[image]
Please advise

[image]

Comment: Add the error you are getting in your command line to the question.

Comment: npx init cypress? That doesn't sound right. Have you tried `npm install cypress --save-dev`?

Comment: i will try that

Comment: @AlapanDas, i have attached the screenshot. It throws an error saying Cypress App cannot be downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. Such an issue came because of security app of our organizations